# Data not returning from async function with database connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The goal is to call a function from my main script that connects to a database, reads a document from it, stores pieces of that document in a new object, and returns that object to my main script. The problem is I cannot get it all to work together. If I try one thing, I get the results but my program locks up. If I try something else I get undefined results.

Long story short, how do I open a database and retrieve something from it to another script.
The program is a quiz site and I want to return the quiz name and the questions.

```
const myDb = require('./app.js');

var myData = myDb.fun((myData) => {
    console.log(myData.quizName);
});
```

Here is the script that tries to open the database and find the data

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const {mongoClient} = require("mongodb");

const uri = connection uri goes here but my name is hard coded into it at the moment so I removed for privacy

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

const fun = async (cback) => {
  try {
    await client.connect();

    const database = client.db('Quiz-Capstone');
    const quizzes = database.collection('Quiz');

    const query = {quizName: "CIS01"};

    const options = {
      sort: {},
      projection: {}
    };

    const quiz = await quizzes.findOne(query, options);

    var quizObject = {
      quizName: quiz.quizName,
      quizQuestions: quiz.quizQuestions
    }

    //console.log(testOb);

  } finally {
    await client.close();
    cback(quizObject);
  }
}


fun().catch(console.dir);


module.exports = {
  fun: fun
}
```

UPDATE: Still stuck. I have read several different threads here about asynchronous calls and callbacks but I cannot get my function located in one file to return a value to the caller located in another file.

Comment: Don't use a callback. Just `return` the value, and use the promise that the function call gives you.

Comment: I have tried that. When I just use a return statement, the value is undefined and my terminal becomes locked like the program is still running.

Comment: How are you calling it from the terminal?

Comment: The first piece of code is in a file called 'main.js' so I am using the command 'node main.js'

Comment: And why would that "lock up"? Are you not getting a result? Did you not close the connection? Please [edit] your question to include the code you tried. It's not clear which version gets you a result but locks up, and which version finishes running but logs undefined.

Comment: I cannot add the code I have tried; its been deleted. I do not know why it is locking up. All I know is I cannot type anything new in my terminal and my fan starts blowing like crazy. I think the issue lies in that the program doesn't think the function has ended but idk.

Comment: If your node script is running infinitly, kill the node process.

Comment: Killing the process does not get me my return value.